# PMD lugin for maven check not showing any violations

Tags: maven, plugins, pmd

I am new to maven and I am trying to introduce PMD plugin into my maven project.

We have used multi module and iam putting the PMD plugin in the parent pom under reporting tag.  I specified the rule sets.

But when I execute the goal

```
mvn pmd:pmd -X
```

I see zero violations.  I do not know whether the source files are scanned or not. In the logs I can very well see that the maven is able to find out the rule set.

Comment: Where are you checking for the violations? In the generated site report?

Comment: when i am executing the maven command mvn pmd:pmd -X . i get logs on the console it self . Just before reactor summary it shows 
Executing PMD...
PMD Finished .. 0 Violations

Comment: Maybe there just aren't any violations? Do you have any reason to expect them? To check whether it's working properly, you could temporarily copy-paste a method that would definitely violate one of the rules.

Comment: i did that i put un used variables and repeated the import statements. Also in the logs it prints generting PMD and return immediately , unlike other reporting plugins ,wherein the execute and generate reports.Hence my sense is  that source files are not getting read. How can i check that ??

Comment: Does `mvn clean install site` work?

Comment: yes it does..infact whn i execute it , it generates all the html files which shows the dependencies and other information in reports.But for PMD its empty

Comment: Do you also see `Executing PMD` in the maven output? It could very well be a bug.

Comment: Yes it did . I tried mvn clean instll pmd: pmd . It worked